# Is there a one-line or more elegant way of returning a newly created object in an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I would like to write this kind of function in just one line, or another more elegant way.
I first constructed a class with some props, and then call and return a promise function within it.

```
 createSomeClass = (props) => {
    this._newClass = new ClassObject(props);
    return this._newClass.callPromise();
  }
```

Comment: This is just fine. Don't shorten it. Unless you really don't actually need the `this._newClass` property afterwards.

Comment: `return new ClassObject(props).callPromise()`

Comment: no need to wrap `new`.

Comment: Both of the above comments are failing to set `this._newClass` If everything the function is doing is important, the way it is currently written is the way it should be written.

Comment: @StefanBlamberg and Isaac Vidrine You guys really shouldnt be giving answers in the comments. Especially considering your answers change functionality. This bypasses the voting system and is very frowned upon.

Comment: @nostromo821 Please get rid of the mindset that shorter code/one liners are better. This leads to ugly, hard to read, hard to maintain code that nobody likes. Aim for clear and concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just one line:

```
  createSomeClass = (props) => (this._newClass = new ClassObject(props)).somePromise()
```

But why do you care? Just making it a oneliner doesn't make the code better at all, just stick to your code and move on to the relevant problems (e.g. *Do you need this method at all? Does it have to be a method?*)